# Can a single qubit gate fidelity be benchmarked through XEB (Cross-Entropy Benchmarking)?

Tags: experimental-realization

I'm currently investigating two qubit Cross-Entropy benchmarking  and was able to simulate the decay curve that one would get in experiment when doing cycles for the case of two qubits (random single qubit gates at each cycle followed by a CZ gate for example). Is it expected to be able to recover a similar fidelity curve for one single qubit, i.e. does it make sense to think about one qubit XEB?
I would have thought that by emulating a depolarising error on each individual single qubit gate, we would be able to recover the exponential decay to extract a per layer error but it does not seem to be the case (the trend would be similar to one qubit RB). Is there any reason why that would not work?

Comment: To be clear: We're talking about XEB averaged over random circuits of varying length, right? Why would you think that the number of qubits matter? I don't get your last two sentences. What doesn't seem to be the case? How is a "trend similar to one qubit RB" bad?

Comment: Yes @MarkusHeinrich, I’m referring to what you describe. Apologies for the confusion. I mean that I have tried to compute the XEB fidelity over random circuits of varying lengths for one single qubit, each cycle consisting of one random single qubit gate subject to depolarizing error. While I would have expected an exponential decay curve proportional to the depolarizing rate, I actually fail to recover such consistent behavior and I am left with oscillating or nearly one XEB fidelity at all times. I was therefore wondering if adjustment of the circuits shall be done for the one qubit case.

Comment: Is the depolarizing error gate-independent? 1) if so you should always get an exponential decay no matter what you are doing (you can do an analytical calculation), and there's probably a bug in your numerics. 2) If not, oscillations would indicate that your gates do not form an (approximate) 2-design. How did you sample?

Comment: for 1) I'm assuming you're using the XEB estimator given as the mean of $2^n p(x|C) - 1$ where $x$ is the observed outcome of the circuit $C$ and $p(x|C)$ is the ideal Born probability.

Comment: The depolarising error is gate independent in the sense that I apply the same error to all gates involved in the circuit. For clarity, I have uploaded my script: https://github.com/arthurostrauss/quantum-scripts/blob/master/xeb_qiskit.ipynb

The post-processing is done in two ways: one is using the log-entropy figure of merit introduced in this paper (Equation 8 in Appendix D): https://journals.aps.org/prl/supplemental/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.120504/supp.pdf

The other is derived from this Cirq example: https://quantumai.google/cirq/noise/qcvv/xeb_theory#estimating_fidelity

Comment: The gate set might perhaps be an issue, I sampled randomly from the three gates that were used in the Google Supremacy paper (X/2, Y/2, SW), but I also checked with other variations.

Comment: The gate set should be fine. Sorry, I cannot check your code, I'm not familiar with qiskit. Given the length of the code, there's plenty of room for bugs, unfortunately. Note that for your simple noise model, you can do a straightforward sanity check: Depolarizing noise commutes with all gates, so you can commute it to the beginning (or end) of the circuit, and multiply it up. If the error probability is $1-p$ and the circuit has $L$ gates, then the you obtain an effective dep. noise with error probability $1-p^L$ in this way. Plug this into the estimators to see the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I have built the estimators you depicted (namely $2^n p(x|C) -1$ and $(1-p)^L$ where p is the depolarising parameter). For the noise model version of the estimator, I recover for the two qubit case (layers of two random single qubit gates followed by CZ gate) a good alignment with the estimators provided by Cirq and the log XEB one given in the appendix of the references I mentioned. However, moving to single qubit case, the noise model depicts indeed the expected behaviour, but the linear XEB does not.

Comment: It seems the latter estimator lacks a normalisation procedure analogous to the log entropy measure (as indicated in https://journals.aps.org/prl/supplemental/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.120504/supp.pdf). I also tried to sample random single qubit gates in the single qubit Clifford group, to ensure a 2-design was used, but without success. I understand the theory to be independent of the number of qubits, but I wonder if in the single qubit case there are two many quantum states that could yield the same distribution as the fully incoherent state, yielding the oscillation around the same value.